# PHP: Text replace the pipe (vertical-bar pipe) character

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following PHP array:

```
$mylist = array('A|B', 'C|D', 'E|F', 'G');
```

Examining this list using

```
print_r($mylist);
```

yields

```
Array ( [0] => A|B [1] => C|D [2] => E|F [3] => G )
```

We would like to do a substitution so that the `|` character is replaced by the string `&vert;` in all elements of the array

In other words

```
print_r($mynewlist);
```

should yield

```
Array ( [0] => A&vert;B [1] => C&vert;D [2] => E&vert;F [3] => G )
```

We have tried a few things like **str_replace**, **preg_replace** and **strtr** but we are not able to make the desired substitution in the array.  We tried escaping the regex character `|` using `\|` and `\\|` but to no avail.

Comment: May I ask why? This is a HTML entity.

Comment: use `htmlentities` to do it for you.

Comment: In response to "May I ask why?" ....... We would like to store the result of a MySQL query into a Pipe Separated File (like CSV but using pipe), which can then be opened by Excel.  In case the data has some `|` character in it, we would like to replace it with its html entity code so that it works in Excel and also looks okay in the webpage.  Are there any better suggestions for doing the same thing?

Comment: Why you didn't use a "normal" csv (with commas) with quoted fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast and trivial solution will be:

```
<?php

$mylist = array('A|B', 'C|D', 'E|F', 'G');

$mylist = str_replace("|","&amp;vert;",$mylist);

print_r($mylist);

?>
```

Works fine!

Comment: If that is the right answer, it must be a very bad question. This changes the encoding to double html encoding. There is no valid reason for double encoding.

Comment: The code works but is it possible to have the result back in an array variable?  We would like to create an PHP function that accepts an array argument and returns a new array, post substitution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `array_map` and `htmlentities` to swap out the `|` character for the HTML encoded equivalent:

```php
$myList = ['A|B', 'C|D', 'E|F', 'G'];

$encoded = array_map(function ($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_HTML5);
}, $myList);

var_dump($encoded);

// Outputs

//    array(4) {
//        [0] =>
//      string(8) "A&vert;B"
//        [1] =>
//      string(8) "C&vert;D"
//        [2] =>
//      string(8) "E&vert;F"
//        [3] =>
//      string(1) "G"
//    }
```

If you are looking to replace just the pipe character, a simple `str_replace` inside the map would also work fine, for example:

```php
$encoded = array_map(function ($string) {
    return str_replace('|', '&vert;', $string);
}, $myList);
```

Comment: when you make a whole edit to your answer it's preferred that you keep the old one and tell us why you made an update.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have a reference for that? I'm also not sure that that warrants a downvote, since the answer is correct & valid.

Comment: Tell me then why you opted from `str_replace` to `htmlentities` ? BTW, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268300/how-should-you-edit-your-own-answer-to-keep-it-up-to-date). Also I didn't downvote.

Comment: Both answers are correct and work fine. I updated the post as I think `htmlentities` is the less brittle options - ie it will work in more cases.

Comment: Why you didn't post that into the answer so everyone who reads would have some benefits. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score -2):

You could use this one:

```
<?php

$mylist = array('A|B', 'C|D', 'E|F', 'G');

// store the results of print_r to a variable
$res = print_r($mylist, TRUE);

// replace all `|` with `&vert;`
$res = str_replace('|', '&vert;', $res);

// output the result
echo $res;
```

Comment: That is a very poor solution, as to use the result in PHP you would have to pass the output of `$res` to `eval()`, which is insecure

Comment: Hi @atymic, I agree that `eval()` indeed imposes a security risk but I feel like what the op needs is just for their own personal use.... I might be wrong though :)